# Assign className conditionally based on source object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a conditional inside a React function that adds a CSS class conditionaly.

**When I add default in all else values the status is getting the 'isUnPublished' class instead of getting the 'default' class..**

If I leave out the default in the 2 first values it shows the default class from the last value.

Code:

STATUS.JS:

```
    const StatusIndicator = (props) => {

    const articleStatus = [

        {
            id: 1,
            name: "published",
            isPublished: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "unpublished",
            isUnPublished: false
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "draft",
            isApproved: false
        }
    ]

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>

 {articleStatus.map(status => <span key={status.id} 
    className={ 
    status.isPublished ? 'published' : 'default' ||
    status.isUnPublished ? 'unpublished' : 'default'|| 
    status.isApproved? 'draft' : 'default'
     }> </span>)}

        </div>
    )
}

export default StatusIndicator;
```

CSS:

```
.published {
    background: rgb(75, 210, 143);
    display: flex;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.unpublished {
    background: rgb(255, 77, 77);
    display: flex;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.draft {
    background: rgb(255, 204, 103);
    display: flex;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.default {
    height: 10px;
    display: flex;
    width: 10px;
    background: #c1c1c1;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Why articleStatus with name = 'published' has a property isPublished which equals false and the one with name = 'unpunlished' has a property isUnPublished which equals false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be somewhat misusing ternary operator. I guess, [it has to be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator#Conditional_chains) something, like:

```
className={ 
    status.isPublished ? 'published' :
    status.isUnPublished ? 'unpublished' : 
    status.isApproved? 'draft' : 'default'
}
```

Comment: Right.. what was i thinking) I see where it went sideways...

Answer (score 1):

For better readability, you can move the class name calculations into a separate method

```
const getClassName = status => {
    switch (true) {
        case status.isPublished:
            return 'published';
        case status.isUnPublished:
            return 'unpublished';
        case status.isApproved:
            return 'draft';
        default:
            return 'default';
    }
};

...

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        {articleStatus.map(status => (
            <span key={status.id} className={getClassName(status)}></span>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Considering `name` already contains required `className`, `switch()` is somewhat excessive, it may be as simple, as that: `getClassName = ({id, name, isPubhished, isUnPublished, isApproved}) =>
    isPublished || isUnPublished || isApproved ? name : 'default'`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov it is not entirely clear which object the OP has, if you look at the provided object, then you can simply set `name` :) `className={status.name}`